# Regular expression for image upload not accepting image with mached regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc

I am using regular expression as data annotation in asp.net mvc as:

```
  [RegularExpression(@"(.*\.)(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)$", ErrorMessage = "Only Image files allowed.")]

    public string LabregCertificateLocation { get; set; }
```

And View is as:

```
     <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label ">Lab Registration Certificate</label>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.LabregCertificateLocation,"",new{ type="file",@class="form-control", @name="LabFile" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LabregCertificateLocation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am getting error message while uploading image of types specified in regular expression.

Comment: When you say error message, is it the validation error "Only images files allowed" ?

Comment: Yes,validation error "Only images files allowed"

Comment: Have you tried debugging, before Model.IsValid, what's the value of `LabregCertificateLocation`?

Comment: The documentation says, for RegularExpressionAttribute a full match is required

Comment: I am getting "System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper" as LabregCertificateLocation value

Comment: @Rupak, an exact match is required, you can try

^.*\.(jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)$
tested on regexTester

Answer (score 0):

The `input type="file"` doesn't return a string to the controller. It returns `HttpPostedFile`. Verify filetype on the client side with JavaScript regex, checking against the value of that field.

[HttpPostedFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httppostedfile?view=netframework-4.8)